# Why don't we have a dedicated Android App?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

A search in the Market for "Stackoverflow" brings up a couple of widgets and question browsing apps, including at least one (Droidstack) where you can add Android-Enthusiasts and browse and search questions, etc, but it's buried fairly deep in the app.

Given the Android Market provides direct access to the exact audience we are looking for, surely a dedicated app would be a good idea? Marketed in the right way (i.e. as a Q&A app for the phone in your hand, rather than talking about stack exchange generally) it could be quite popular and presumably generate a fair amount of traffic.

This seems a bit obvious, so apologies if it has already been explored and I've missed it. If not, then what could we do to make it happen?

Comment: Don't know if things have changed in the StackExchange API recently, but the big problem used to be that the API only allowed Read access to the sites, you couldn't ask/answer questions or vote. All of which are fairly fundamental things users will want in a stand-alone app.

Answer (score 3):

For one, we are still in Beta (we don't even have a permanent site design yet!). And for two, it takes some effort to write and maintain such program, and since DroidStack is still very unstable (it crashes all the time in my phone), it would be too early to fork DroidStack's development to support specific sites.

It's a good idea though, I'd think there would be many Android users that don't need/want the full stack exchange network. Maybe sometime after we graduated and we had a permanent site design, someone can start hacking on [DroidStack's code](http://code.google.com/p/droidstack/) with a matching design and settings.

Comment: That's true, while forking another app is a possibility it's probably not worth someone writing us an app from scratch while we're still in beta, when there is still (a hopefully very slim) chance that we might never launch.

Answer (score 2):

To answer part of your question:

> … so apologies if it has already been explored and I've missed it. If not, then what could we do to make it happen?

Here is a great resource to explore and ask questions about application and developing for the Stack Exchange sites: [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com)

Comment: True @Robert, but he has a point that having an app will make users find us in the Android Market too.